# using SCILAB find count of elements in an array that meet certain condition

Tags: scilab

suppose that i have an array ID= [ 5 9 5 9 0 ]
by using while loop i want to find number of elemnts that are greater than 5
and the number of elemnt less than 5
by using scilab Code

Comment: I removed the Matlab tag, since this question does not seem to be about Matlab

Comment: scilab is just a free version of matlab

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Scilab answers. Just tune it for any of your own user cases:

```
--> a = [2 4 4 9 8 5 0 9 9 7 2 5 1 5 3 5 6 0 4 6];

--> sum(a>7)
 ans  =
   4.

--> sum(a<=3)
 ans  =
   6.

--> sum(a<=3 | a>7)
 ans  =
   10.
```

Comment: thanks , but this is not a scilab code

Comment: Sure it is. What else are you expecting?

Comment: I need the solution in SCILAB code please

Comment: Just extract the Scilab instructions from the whole sequence.